# Is it possible to copy objects from a runner on a GitLabCI server to another runner on another GitLabCI server?

Tags: image, gitlab, containers, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to copy container images from a runner on one server to a runner on another server is that possible? I am new to CI/CD and do not know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to build an image on one runner, then transfer it to another, you can not do that directly.
you have to upload it to a shared registry.

you might want to explain what you want to achieve a little deeper, are you looking to share the runner image itself? or an image that lives inside the job?

for the latter there might be a workaround, if you save the image to file with `docker save`, then use the gitlab-ci `artifacts:` statement to save the file for later use in another job. but this is probably not what you want.
(using artifacts is generally the way to preserve files from one job for another (running later) one